# Output on TRUE values

Tags: r, statistics

I have a dataframe 'df' with columns Site_name and Race. The Site_name has 4 categories and Race has 6 categories out of which one is called as 'Missing'.

I want to display only count of 'Missing' for each Site_name. I am using the following code.

```
dplyr::count(df, Site_name, Race %in% "Missing")
```

The output I am getting is as:

| Site_name | Race %in% "Missing" | n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | TRUE | 64 |
| a | FALSE | 231 |
| b | TRUE | 75 |
| b | FALSE | 213 |
| c | TRUE | 23 |
| c | FALSE | 73 |
| d | TRUE | 8 |
| d | FALSE | 12 |

But I would like to output only TRUE values like below:

| Site_name | Race %in% "Missing" | n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | TRUE | 64 |
| b | TRUE | 75 |
| c | TRUE | 23 |
| d | TRUE | 8 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group_by` + `summarise` and use `sum` to count number of values with  `"Missing"` value for each `Site_name`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Site_name) %>% summarise(n = sum(Race %in% "Missing"))
```

Comment: this returned me the total count and not the count for each individual Site_name

Comment: You might have loaded `plyr` which is masking the `summarise` function. Try using `dplyr::summarise`.

Comment: Sorry my bad i used dplyr:: group_by. Now I am getting the correct output. Thanks.

Comment: If I want to add another percentage columns as well for the above output how can it be done? Like a = 64 and total count is 1000 then it would be 64% and same for b,c,d.

Comment: You can create another column in `summarise`. Add `perc = n/n() * 100` i.e `df %>% dplyr::group_by(Site_name) %>% dplyr::summarise(n = sum(Race %in% "Missing"), perc = n/n() * 100)`

Comment: That helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R`

```
aggregate(cbind(n = Race %in% "Missing") ~ Site_name, df, FUN = sum)
```